# Haskell error load module with mysql

Tags: haskell, do-notation

Haskell : Database.MySQL.Base

```
insert_Producto  = do
    conn <- connect
    defaultConnectInfo {ciUser = "root", ciPassword = "", ciDatabase = "prueba"}
    oks <- executeMany conn "delete from producto"
```

load Module :

```
Conexion.hs:27:5: error:
    The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression
      oks <- executeMany conn "delete from producto"
   |
27 |     oks <- executeMany conn "delete from producto"
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I try to load the module, but it marks me error.
Does anyone know what would be the right way to do it?

Comment: how are "insert_Producto" and "delete from producto" related?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that this is the code you are executing:

```
import Database.MySQL.Base

insert_Producto = do
    conn <- connect (defaultConnectInfo {ciUser = "root", ciPassword = "", ciDatabase = "prueba"})
    oks <- executeMany conn "delete from producto" []
```

The compiler is complaining because you bind `executeMany` to the variable `oks` in the final line of a `do` block. If you want your do block to return the output of `executeMany`, you could do this:

```
insert_Producto1 = do
    conn <- connect (defaultConnectInfo {ciUser = "root", ciPassword = "", ciDatabase = "prueba"})
    executeMany conn "delete from producto" []
```

The reason why your code is problematic is that `do` notation is desugared to a series of binds (`>>=`). The code you wrote would be transformed to

```
insert_Producto2 = connect (defaultConnectInfo {ciUser = "root"
                                               , ciPassword = ""
                                               , ciDatabase = "prueba"})
                       >>= \conn ->
                           executeMany conn "delete from producto" []
                               >>= \oks ->
                                   <???>
```

As you can see, there is no body in the last lambda function, which causes the error. The code block I proposed above would desugar to:

```
insert_Producto1 = connect (defaultConnectInfo {ciUser = "root"
                                               , ciPassword = ""
                                               , ciDatabase = "prueba"})
                       >>= \conn ->
                           executeMany conn "delete from producto" []
```

The last lambda now had a complete body.

Comment: Thanks for your time answering, testing insert_Product2 throws me error:

Comment: • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO a0’
                  with actual type ‘[p1] -> IO OK’
    • Probable cause: ‘execute’ is applied to too few arguments
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: execute conn "delete from producto"

      In the expression:
        do conn <- connect
                     defaultConnectInfo
                       {ciUser = "root", ciPassword = "", ciDatabase = "prueba"}
           execute conn "delete from producto"
           close conn
      In an equation for ‘delete_Producto’:

Comment: What is the type of `executeMany`? It looks like it takes an additional list argument, which hasn’t been supplied.

Comment: Esta es la sentencia:                                                                     
executeMany :: QueryParam p => MySQLConn -> Consulta -> [[p]] -> IO [OK]

Comment: Ah, ok. So it takes a list of query parameters. As background context: the way to read that type signatures is that the 3 types to the left of the last `->` are arguments, and the type on the right is the return type. So this function needs 3 arguments to be fully applied. You can pass `[]` if you don’t have any query parameters. I’ve just updated the above code blocks.

Comment: Next message :
 • Ambiguous type variable ‘p0’ arising from a use of ‘executeMany’
      prevents the constraint ‘(QueryParam p0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘p0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance QueryParam MySQLValue
          -- Defined in ‘mysql-haskell-0.8.3.0:Database.MySQL.Query’
        instance QueryParam Param
          -- Defined in ‘mysql-haskell-0.8.3.0:Database.MySQL.Query’